# React Native Screen freezes scrollview in iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, freeze, react-native-scrollview, react-native-screens

I'm having a problem with **react-native-screens**. My version was **2.9.0** and I updated with the latest version **2.15.2**. After I updated it to the latest version it freezes the scrollview under my @react-navigation/bottom-tabs. The other screens are working well but I noticed when the screen has a scrollview you cannot click nor scroll. How to solved this issue? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: can't you show me some detail?

Comment: @Jals here are the versions 

 "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
 "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
 "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.16",
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1",

I don't know what is the reason. sometimes it is working. But when i navigate back, it froze the whole app.

Comment: was this working for you earlier? if yes, can you please share the package versions u were using?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this bug too. I updated packages and now it's ok.
Here my versions:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.6",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.1",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
```